# N1QL - query multilevel nested JSON data in CouchBase

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

How do I select the whole JSON document by querying for multi level nested values? Here is example of my JSON:

```
{
  "id": "6316194187233559482",
  "type": "Hotel",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "country": "Germany",
      "officialNames": [
          {
            "name": "The Ritz-Carlton, Berlin",
            "language": "GER"
          }
      ],
      "streetsAndCities": [
          {
              "city": "Berlin",
              "cityLanguage": "GER",
              "street": "Potsdamer Platz ",
              "streetLanguage": "GER"
          }
      ]   
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to query it for "name" attribute. I have experimented with UNNEST function and I have no problem to acces first level of nested data i.e. "officialNames". But I don't know how to access "name" attribute. Referencing it by position e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM document 
UNNEST attributes as attributes
WHERE attributes[0].officialNames[0].name = "The Ritz-Carlton, Berlin"
```

Is not going to work as position of each attribute in JSON can change.

Comment: May [global-secondary-indexes](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/architecture/global-secondary-indexes.html) helps you?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "position of each attribute in JSON can change"? Do you mean that the "attributes" and "officialNames" and "streetsAndCities" arrays can have additional entries and you want to search through all the entries?

If yes, then have a look at the ANY operator here:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html

Comment: By "position of each attribute in JSON can change" I meant that "officialNames" has array of objects in which "name" is not always on position [0]. My JSON data can be very complex/nested hence I don't think referencing by position will work.

Comment: OK, I think you should reconsider your data model somewhat. Use arrays (with []) only for repeated elements, and maps (with {}) for collections of elements. You have control over order in arrays; you do not have control over order in maps. This article addresses JSON modelling: https://blog.couchbase.com/json-data-modeling-rdbms-users/

Comment: In any case, if you want to refer to the value "The Ritz-Carlton, Berlin", you  can do that as `attributes[0].officialNames[0].name`

Comment: Regarding reconsideration of data model. I have not option to change it. I am only end user of data meaning I can only query it.